# Rebar in the way inside a concrete lintel

Tags: fixings

While drilling to fix brackets to a concrete lintel using 50mm long rawlbolts (75mm bolts), I've hit something inside the lintel. Only guess it's rebar. And, of course it's the last hole!

I've gone in by around 40mm, so the rawlbolt fitting is proud. What solutions have you guys come up with for this problem?

Comment: In case of an lintel, I'd think that you hit a pre-stressing wire. I'd avoid cutting it.

Depending on circumstances (what's the load on the bracket?) you can perhaps work around the issue?

Comment: What is the bracket for?  If you are mounting a full size SUV to your wall then you probably want the full fastener embeded in the concrete.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger - I've run out of SUVs, so this time, it's a 20' stringer, 60mm x 180mm end on, for a pergola - supported further along its length with upstands, so heavy, but not quite as heavy as an SUV.

Comment: I'd want that last bolt hole.  Can you take a picture of the bracket?  Is this 1/4" thick steel or something closer to a joist hanger in metal thickness?

Answer (score 3):

Cut the fitting down, glue it in and cut the bolt to fit.